# Using gacutil to install a .dll

Tags: c#, dll, gacutil

I am trying to install a .dll refrence to use it in my code, but i am having issues using the gacutil. Would anyone be able to help me with the format of this?

I have tried using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c.aspx
But i must still be doing something wrong...

the .dll that i am trying to install is `Office.dll`

Here is what i have tried:

```
gacutil /i Office.dll "C:\File\path\Office.dll"
```

It comes up with an error saying:

```
Unknown option: C:\File\path\Office.dll
```

Would anyone have any ideas to help me with this?

Comment: Why are you gaking the assembly instead of just putting it in your application's bin folder?

Comment: Don't do that.  It is a PIA, it needs to be properly registered.  Download the correct version from Microsoft and run its installer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need the second param

just use :

`gacutil /i "C:\File\path\Office.dll"`

Answer (score 4):

You can easily add dll to GAC using `Publish` class. Add reference to `System.EnterpriseServices`

```
System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish publish = new System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish();
publish.GacInstall("dll path");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `gacutil /i "C:\File\path\Office.dll"`. Also please note that assembly must be strongly named to be installed correctly in GAC.